# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

While debugging I got this error in my below part of code..

```
 queryStirngValue = document.referrer.split("myQuryString")[1].split("%")[1].split("253D")[1];
    alert(queryStirngValue);
```

Comment: Seems look like you having blank value in string and you are trying to perform split operation. can you check what you get in document.referrer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 document.referrer.split("myQuryString")[1].split("%")
```

You first split on `myQuryString` (*which by itself is misspelled?*)

With [1] you then want the **second** array value (because arrays start at 0)

So if `myQuryString` is not in the QueryString you now have a `null` value

So

```
null.split("%")
```

causes: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined(…)*